# Using git inside docker containers

Tags: git, docker

I am using Docker-compose to split my webapp into two containers.
The project folder hierarchy looks like this:

- app/

  - .git/
  - frontend/

    - Dockerfile
  - backend/

    - Dockerfile
  - docker-compose.yml

I am using the Remote-Containers extension on VSCode to work directly inside my containers, so that I won't have to rebuild my containers for every change. I also want to use git inside my container too. But I am not sure how I can copy the .git/ folder into my container because it is outside the Dockerfile's context.

My docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
    angular: # name of the first container
        build: ./frontend
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
    
    express: # name of the second container
        build: ./backend
        ports:
            - "8081:8081"
```

My frontend/Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10.18.0-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY ./../.git .   # doesn't work!

# copy package.json & install dependencies
COPY package.json .
RUN npm cache clean --force
RUN npm install

# copy files to /usr/src/app
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080

# call start script from package.json
CMD ["npm","start"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure that copying a `.git` directory is a good idea. But if you are sure it's necessary, here is how you can get this.

The `docker build [OPTIONS] PATH` command builds Docker images from a Dockerfile and a "context". A build’s context is the set of files located in the specified `PATH`.

So, in a Dockerfile you can't reference directories that are not in the build context.

```
COPY ./../.git .   # parent directory of the build context doesn't work!
```

Instead, you can build the Dockerfile from the parent directory.
Edit the `frontend/Dockerfile`

```
#...
WORKDIR /usr/src/app 
COPY .git . 
COPY frontend . 
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/frontend 
#...
RUN npm install
#...
```

and use the following command

```
docker build -t angular-frontend -f frontend/Dockerfile .
```

or in `docker-compose.yaml`

```
services:
  angular:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: frontend/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm able to see my git log from inside my container.
I am facing another problem: Literally every project file in my container is marked as modified. Do you know why this might be happening? Or is this a different problem unrelated to Docker?

Comment: You have to preserve the directory structure: 
`WORKDIR /usr/src/app`
`COPY .git .`
`COPY frontend .`
`WORKDIR /usr/src/app/frontend`
`RUN npm install`

Comment: @wO_o How did you even get Git to recognize your credentials from within the Docker container? I tried to do the same but clearly all the SSH keys used in the host aren't visible from the Docker container. Cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77595423/using-git-from-a-docker-container

Comment: @Tfovid This issue was a while back, so I don't remember what I did to get it working. But from one of my more recent projects where I had a similar problem, I mounted the ~/.ssh directory from my host to the container as a volume like this:
`docker run -v ~/.ssh:/root/.ssh my_image`.
Fyi this solution is risky since you don't want the container to leak your entire .ssh keys.