# Using Git from a Docker container

Tags: git, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

For the sake of avoiding any dependency issues, I am attempting to do all my development from within Docker. In other words, although I have a Git repo on the host, I'd like to do all the coding from within Docker so as to avoid cluttering my host with `pip` installs I'll eventually lose track of.

The way I go about this is to mount my repo (along with its `.git` directory) via `docker-compose.yml`. I then get into the container with `docker compose run myservice`, where `myservice` was defined by the `docker-compose.yml`. Once inside the container's shell, however, a simple run of `git status` returns the following error message.

```
fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at '/home'
To add an exception for this directory, call:

        git config --global --add safe.directory /home
```

So, clearly, Git has some issue recognizing the `root` user within as the legitimate user `tfovid` from the host. I tried to fix this by adding `user: 1000:1000` in the `docker-compose.yml` but that's leading to other issues (e.g., that I don't have any username in the container anymore).

Interestingly, when I do not mount the volumes, `git` works fine until I attempt to push, at which point it returns the following error.

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

How can I solve this? Basically, I only want to use the host for storage of the repo (including the `.git` subdirectory). Everything else should be done from Docker.

Below is the full `docker-compose.yml`. `$DIR_LOC` is the Git rpo at the host.

```
version: '0'
services:
  myservice:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: $IMAGE_URI
#    user: 1000:1000
    entrypoint: /bin/bash                                                                                                              working_dir: /home/
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
#    volumes:
#      - $DIR_LOC:$DIR_REM
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "200k"
        max-file: "10"
```

Note: There is a question with the [same title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63953407/using-git-inside-docker-containers) but it should be clear that the context in which it is different.

Comment: Git in docker is ok, user mapping is ok, public key is not ok because you do not have this key added on GitHub, BitBucket, etc…

Comment: Python virtual environments? - never heard.

Comment: A workaround is to use http/https URL of the repository instead of ssh, so that you can use username/password/token for authentication.

Comment: @ElpieKay Could you please expand a bit on that HTTPS alternative? I.e., how should I change the `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml`?

Comment: @MaximColesnic So what's the alternative?

Comment: @Ryan I am not sure what you mean. I didn't make any reference to Python. I'd just like to be able to use Git from within the container the same way I do in the host.

Comment: The ssh url is like `git@github.com:foo/bar.git`. The https one would be `https://${username}:${token}@github.com/foo/bar.git`. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74522931/6330106) can help.